# Raspberry Pi OS - 2 WLAN interfaces (onboard + USB dongle), 2 SSIDs

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi-os

I have a RPi 4 8GB with the latest Raspberry Pi OS (August 2020) installed. I need to connect to 2 different APs:

- wlan0: onboard
- wlan1: USB dongle

Here is the configuration so far:

- /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=XX

network={
        ssid="AP1"
        psk="XXXXXXXX"
        scan_ssid=1
}
```

- /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=XX

network={
        ssid="AP2"
        psk="XXXXXXXX"
}
```

- /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.178.100/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.179.2/24
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
```

When I boot the RPi, then:

- the wlan0 becomes wlan1
- and...the wlan1 becomes wlan0
- the wlan1 (onboard WiFi interface) connects to AP2
- the wlan0 (USB dongle) is down

How can I get wlan0 & wlan1 working?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED: Solution**

My feedback regarding the predictable network interface names AND the udev rules:

- Predictable network interface names: Enabling this option (raspi-config -> 2 Network Options -> N3 Network interface names Enable/Disable predictable network interface names) was not **always** assigning (after a reboot) the onboard WLAN as wlan0.
- UDEV rules: Such a rule based on the MAC is a good option, but requires that the MAC defined within the rule has to be changed...if the WLAN USB dongle is replaced. I found a more suitable solution (at least for me) here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198946. In this scenario the USB port will be defined for assigning the interface name "wlan1".

Here is the final configuration:

The WLAN USB dongle will be plugged in the upper left USB port of a RPi 4. The /etc/udev/rules.d/72-wlan-geo-dependent.rules is accordingly as follows:

- /etc/udev/rules.d/72-wlan-geo-dependent.rules

```
# Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
#
# +---------+ ----------+
# | USB 2.0 | | USB 3.0 |
# | 1-1.3   | | 1-1.1   | +------+
# +---------+ +---------+ |      |
# | USB 2.0 | | USB 3.0 | | LAN  |
# | 1-1.4   | | 1-1.2   | |      |
# +---------+ +---------+ +------+

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="sdio", KERNELS=="mmc1:0001:1", NAME="wlan0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNELS=="1-1.3",       NAME="wlan1"
```

- /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=XX

network={
        ssid="AP1"
        psk="XXXXXXXX"
        scan_ssid=1
}
```

- /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=XX

network={
        ssid="AP2"
        psk="XXXXXXXX"
}
```

- /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.178.100/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.1

interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.179.2/24
```

Comment: Is `dmeswpa-conf` a real error or just a transcription error on here? Should be `wpa-conf ...`.

Comment: Thanks, It was an editing error from my side. It is wpa-conf ... in the /etc/dhcpcd.conf .

Comment: There is no `wpa-conf` directive in `dhcpcd` - you can't just invent things and expect them to work. Have you read the man page?

Comment: Indeed there is no such directive. But I found some descriptions about this setup, where they used to use the wpa-conf in the dhcpcd.conf. I removed these lines from the solution that I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your rather vague Question you are asking about the allocation of names to Network Interfaces.

You should use Predictable Network Interface Names which have been used in other distributions for some time.

These are designed for multiple network interfaces to eliminate the enumeration race condition.

There is an option in raspi-config to enable predictable network interface names.

See **Predictable Network Interface Names** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for further detail.

**Use different wpa_supplicant files** explains how to configure dhcpcd to use different wpa_supplicant.conf files for a specific wireless interface.

You may also want to look at **Prevent dhcpcd from configuring a gateway on an interface**

Comment: No, I am asking...how I can get it working: wlan0 connect to AP1 and wlan1 connect to AP2. I think that networking setup was "easier" before Buster...like in Jessie by using the /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Your Comment doesn't make anything clearer - NOTE you should **edit your Question** to add detail. There is NO way you can ensure wlan0/wlan1 are allocated to specific interfaces (although it may be possible with by writing udev rules based on MAC - but this is what  Predictable Network Interface Names do.) as these are allocated in the order they are enumerated. The on-board WiFi should win as it is connected by sdio. The later OS are NO DIFFERENT to Wheezy (which was the last to use  Debian networking) there has ALWAYS been a race condition.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback regarding the predictable network interface names and udev rules. This was at least a point for me to start investigating it!